# Retrieving Facebook's App-Scoped IDs from Page-Scoped ID returns empty result

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I would like to link users interacting with ShoppingPage to existing account on ShoppingMobile app if any. In other words, the use case "Given a user ID for a bot in Messenger, retrieve the IDs for apps owned by the same business" described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching/#given-a-user-id-for-a-bot-in-messenger--retrieve-the-ids-for-apps-owned-by-the-same-business

I have 2 apps and 2 pages owned by the same business account:

**Apps**

1. **ShoppingMobile** - app with iOS and Android platforms and Facebook login enabled

   1.1. **ShoppingMobileTest** - Test app created from ShoppingMobile
2. **ShoppingBot** - app with only Messenger and Webhook configured. Not applied for `manage_pages` and `pages_messaging` permissions yet.

   2.1. **ShoppingBotTest** - Test app created from ShoppingBot

**Pages**

1. **ShoppingPage** - managed by ShoppingBot
2. **ShoppingPageBeta** - managed by ShoppingBotTest

During development, I tried to get ASIDs from PSID generated by ShoppingBotTest app using `GET /{psid}/ids_to_apps` endpoint. When using my own PSID (the same account that generates page access token), I can get associated ASIDs as expected. 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/2864546363594516/?method=GET&path=2090502677643890%2Fids_for_apps&version=v6.0

However, when I tried another PSID of my colleague who has Tester role in ShoppingBotTest app, empty result is returned. I already made sure both I and my colleague logged in ShoppingMobileTest app using the same account as the one interacting with ShoppingBotTest.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/2864546363594516/?method=GET&path=3755682274504767%2Fids_for_apps&version=v6.0

The odd thing is, when I made my colleague generate page access token and retry with this token, I can get my colleage’s ASIDs as expected and my PSID returns empty result. It seems `GET /{psid}/ids_to_apps` only returns result when using with page access token PSID owner generated.

What could I do to ensure PSID-to-ASID matching would work with every user before submit ShoppingBot for App Review for manage_pages and pages_messaging permissions?